# Cloud hosted VM's that can connect to my company LAN

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, lan, amazon-ec2

I am a Quality Assurance engineer, and I am not an expert in Networking. Currently, I have 4 Windows VMs running on a server on our local network. They communicate with each other using Selenium Grid for testing. But they also need to be on our LAN to access some of our test environments.

Is there a good cloud based solution that can achieve the same thing? I have looked into Amazon EC2 and VPC, but was told that there is a hardware requirement, some "customer gateway" that costs several thousand dollars, that is needed to connect 4 EC2 instances to my local network.

Perhaps there is another hosting service that can run VM's on our VPN, or directly connect to our network somehow?

I either need all 4 of these VMs running in a persistant state, or only one of them, and the others can be spun up on demand.

Comment: You have been told wrong. You can integrate your AWS properties with your network using standard IPSec tunnels - no $4k hardware required as there are free software implementations - its a very standardised spec. See section "How does an AWS Site-to-Site VPN connection work with Amazon VPC?" at https://aws.amazon.com/vpn/faqs/ . Unfortunately the question you asked is off topic here as its a shopping recommendation.

Comment: @dsidler, does your org have a DevOps Engineer (or a SysAdmin or NetAdmin)? Get him/her involved and make your lives much, much easier. No offense, but this is what happens when Devs try and do systems and network work. No one can specialize in everything IT, after all!

Comment: Let me guess, a Sales "Engineer" told you that you "need" (lol) that expensive customer gateway.